# Compiling error in Codeblocks undefined reference to `__gmpz_mul_ui'

Tags: compiler-errors, codeblocks, gmp

So I'm trying to compile this code here in Codeblocks :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmpxx.h>

using namespace std;

void
myfunction (mpz_t result, mpz_t param, unsigned long n)
{
  unsigned long  i;

  mpz_mul_ui (result, param, n);
  for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    mpz_add_ui (result, result, i*7);
}

int
main (void)
{
  mpz_t  r, n;
  mpz_init (r);
  mpz_init_set_str (n, "123456", 0);

  myfunction (r, n, 20L);
  mpz_out_str (stdout, 10, r); printf ("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

and i get this error when i go to compile

```
    -------------- Build: Debug in orcs (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -L..\..\Lzip\gmp-6.1.0 -L..\..\Lzip\gmp-6.1.0 -o bin\Debug\orcs.exe obj\Debug\main.o   ..\..\Lzip\mybuilddir\.libs\libgmpxx.a
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `Z10myfunctionP12__mpz_structS0_m':
C:/Users/Joe.Joe/Documents/FMC/orcs/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `__gmpz_mul_ui'
C:/Users/Joe.Joe/Documents/FMC/orcs/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `__gmpz_add_ui'
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `main':
C:/Users/Joe.Joe/Documents/FMC/orcs/main.cpp:20: undefined reference to `__gmpz_init'
C:/Users/Joe.Joe/Documents/FMC/orcs/main.cpp:21: undefined reference to `__gmpz_init_set_str'
C:/Users/Joe.Joe/Documents/FMC/orcs/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `__gmpz_out_str'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
5 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Now I have looked into the this problem on google, but those solutions i have found dont seem to be working.

Right now under Project> Build Options > Search Directories > Linker , I have the location of gmp-6.1.0

I have tried putting gmp In the Project > Build Options > Linker Settings > Other Linker Options , however this doesnt work and instead gives me this :

```
-------------- Build: Debug in orcs (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -L..\..\Lzip\gmp-6.1.0 -L..\..\Lzip\gmp-6.1.0 -o bin\Debug\orcs.exe obj\Debug\main.o  gmp  ..\..\Lzip\mybuilddir\.libs\libgmpxx.a
mingw32-g++.exe: error: gmp: No such file or directory
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

I'm not exactly sure where the problem is, because I'm pretty sure everything was installed in the default place. Hopefully this is enough info to help me out :)

Comment: I presume you extracted `gmp-6.1.0` into `..\..\Lzip\gmp-6.1.0` and built
it in `..\..\Lzip\mybuilddir`. Please include in your post the commands
you used to build the package. That will make it easier for me to tell you
how to do it right.

Comment: You need to link with `libgmp.a`, not just `libgmpxx.a`.

Comment: Using Cygwin , i cd to the mybuilddir .   Then I did the following commands '..\..\lzip\gmp-6.1.0\configure    > make > make check > make install. Everything appeared to be done correct and i didnt see any errors.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Can you tell me how to do that? I'm kinda a noob when it comes to compilers and linkers,

Comment: If you have simply run `./configure; make; make check; make install` then you haven't configured to build `libgmpxx`. For that you need `./configure --enable-cxx`. Is that what you did, or where did your ` ..\..\Lzip\mybuilddir\.libs\libgmpxx.a` come from?

Comment: well i guess it configured in the folder labeled `...\Lzip\mybuilddir` , Just to be sure i reconfigured it (cd to the mybuilddir folder and then configured with --enable-cxx , everything else same as before ) .  Its still giving me the `undefined refernce to gmpz mul_ui` and stuff.

Comment: I SOLVED IT-  For some reason, Codeblocks default compiler wasnt the Cygwin, so i switched that and set up all the deffault things, and now it works. Shout out to Marc and Mike for getting me in the right direction! <3 love you guys